# django 1.5 with mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I would like to work with the django(currently 1.5.2) with the mongodb (currently 2.4.6).
Till now I had tried:

1. mongodbengine: didn't like inherit from a Document class ([he said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972480/has-anybody-actually-used-django-mongodb/9306519#9306519) it better).
2. django-mongodb-engine which was exactly what I wanted only when it runs my django jumps to 1.3 instead of the 1.5.2 [I didn't give it much thought, guessed its the norel from the 1.3 branch and assuming it would be best to stay at 1.5.2].
3. looke at [those](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tools.html#alternative-drivers) and trying to save myself some time asking here..

Please advise, my goal is to run django 1.5.2 (with virtualenv) so I could use normal models with mongodb DB. 
What is the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that `django` and `mongoengine` do not have an integration yet, but its still in the works. If you want to use `mongoengine`, I would suggest that you use flask, because the other way you have to use it is rather frustrating, wherein you need to connect to `mongodb` using a cursor, in your `models.py` file and then inheriting from `Document` to make your classes.

Thus, every single time you need to use your models, you will need to connect back, hitting your database several times over. This is not how django usually operates, since it uses one connection to handle multiple queries to make things more efficient.

This becomes a REAL pain in the long run, and I would strong discourage you using django and `mongoengine` or `mongodb` for that matter, and especially for a person who is brand new to django in the first place.

If you're new to django, then please use a RDBMS like `Sqlite3` or `PostgreSQL` to do your development. But if the use of `mongodb` is a *must*, then I suggest that you reconsider using django in the first place, because `mongodb` has a better integration with flask, through `mongoengine`.

And I would suggest that you do not use anything other than `mongoengine` when dealing with `mongodb`, because `mongoengine` has the best support for `mongodb`, and is *by far* the most flexible option out there when working with `mongodb` and python. Not only that, but the syntax is almost identical to that of django's ORM.

I deeply regret I cannot provide a better answer, the only solutions remains making a connection every single time, and not to mention that all of this does not integrate well with django's forms, which is a big bummer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a SQL relational database for the `django` models like User. Then you can use a [Database Router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) to route based on the app name, if it's `auth` then use the relational database. This will let you specify by app/model which database to use.

An example from someone on this site: [Mixing Postgres and Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5757011/344156).